# Checking if data exists working, but doesn't display what I'm asking it too

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay, so, I'm checking whether to see if random data selected from a php array already exists within my database.

Here is the code for the snippet that is not working.

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM contest WHERE Loser = '".$input[$rand_keys[$i]]."' AND Hamantha = '".$input[$rand_keys[$i+30]]."'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if ($data[$i] > 1){

            while($data[$i] > 1){
             echo'DO NOT USE THIS GUESS';
            $rand_keys2 = array_rand($input, 2);
            $input[$rand_keys[0]] = $input[$rand_keys[$i]];
            $input[$rand_keys[1]] = $input[$rand_keys[$i + 30]];
            }
            echo $input[$rand_keys2[0]];
            echo '-';
            echo $input[$rand_keys2[1]];
            echo '<br>';
        } else {

            echo $input[$rand_keys[$i]];
            echo '-';
            echo $input[$rand_keys[$i + 30]];
            echo'<br>';
        }
```

it displays the data that doesn't exist correctly, but when it does exist, the code under the 'if' doesn't run. I put error_reporting on, and all the lines that the data does exist for, it shows an error for all those lines, which is good, it's finding the lines that do exist within the database, yet the stuff under the if don't run why? Like it doesn't display 'DO NOT USE THIS GUESS' ect.

Edit: Here is a picture of the problem i.imgur.com/F35vGzO.png

As you see if found the first guess to be good, while the second guess was already used, but it didn't display the messages i wanted it to.

Comment: Shouldn't the if and while statements' conditions be `>= 1` or `> 0` instead of `> 1`?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I've used both, and still none of them run after trying.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, changing my above query state to this worked perfectly.

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbl, "SELECT * FROM `tblUser` WHERE email='".$email."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

echo "email already exists";
}....
```